# Profile dll source code using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2017, profiling

I've written some code that is compiled as a .dll for use a s a plugin in some other software and i'm trying to figure out how or if I can improve the performance of the code.

I've managed to run the performance profiler within VS2017 (output below) but it's pretty difficult to work out what is what. I can see something is using 42% of the time, something else 15%, etc, but I'd like to know what function or line of code is what to see if that time can be reduced. How do I do this in a quick and easy way? Is the string after the dll name an identifier I can use to find out what each one is?

[image: VS2017 Profiler output for dll]

Comment: You probably want to build the `RelWithDebugInfo` configuration instead of `Release`.

Comment: I've also tried with debug, but if you try to run the profile tool with the debug version you get a warning: "Solution configuration is set to debug. Switch to release for more accurate results".

Comment: Should get enough symbols in Release build, if you build a .pdb and include it in the test folder where the .dll is

Comment: @WilliamClements my pdb file is in the same folder as the dll, yet VS complains " Cannot find or open the PDB file.". There's also an .ipdb - is that required too?

Comment: @jpmorr See Tools->Options->Debugging ->Symbols ... you probably need to add that path for the debugger to pick it up

Comment: Adding the .ipdb and restarting after lunch seems to have been enough to make things more understandable, but the output still doesn't show the % time spent on calling each namespace function. Is there any way to view this?